# Dynamically generated content's html tags not showing the text while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

While I was inspecting the myntra product web page's product info like Title, Discount, and Price. I used the same tags as I saw while inspecting that page in chrome browser and then put that into my code,
Please look at this code :

```
import requests
import random
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def headerrs():
    """
    return different random headers
    """
    ua = UserAgent()

    head1 = {'User-Agent': ua.random,
             'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
             'Accept-Charset': 'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3',
             'Accept-Encoding': 'none',
             'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
             'Connection': 'keep-alive'
             }

    return head1



def get_html_page(link):
    """
    get product price
    :param product_page_soup: bs4 soup: soup of a product page
    :return: string
    """
    top_page = requests.get(link, headers=headerrs())
    top_soup = BeautifulSoup(top_page.content, 'lxml')
    top_details = top_soup.find('div',{'class' : 'pdp-details'})
    top_title = top_details.find('h1', {'class' : 'pdp-title'}).text.strip()
    top_discount = top_details.find('span', {'class' : 'pdp-discount'}).text.strip()
    top_price = top_details.find('b', {'class' : 'pdp-price'}).text.strip()
    print('Title : '+str(top_title)+', Discount : '+str(top_discount)+', Price : '+str(top_price))

links = 'https://www.myntra.com/amp/tunics/nayo/nayo-white--black-printed-tunic/5414881/buy'

get_html_page(links)
```

but when I ran this piece of code I got this output

```
Title : Nayo White & Black Printed Tunic, Discount : {{style.price.discount.label}}, Price : Rs. {{style.price.discounted}}
```

Actually I don't know how to get this dynamically generated content that is the text in my output, I want to know how to get the text without using selenium as selenium is hell lot of a slow process to load each product consequently from the e-commerce site myntra.

Comment: Content  is dynamically generated. You need a method like selenium to allow time for that content to be available.

Comment: @QHarr hey I know about that selenium but that is too slow and wouldn't be good for mass data mining from any ecommerce site like myntra, 

is there something else to get that?

Comment: Try keeping some initial time delay, say of 4s. Let the page get rendered completely first and then run your code.

Comment: @VikasYadav how would I do that into my code can you show me that?

Comment: if you don't want to use selenium, try looking up `html-requests`. I believe their is an option that allows you render the page first. But I'm not familar with that package

Comment: Disable the javascript on your browser and navigate to your site. You'll get the same result.

Comment: @chitown88 okay man!

Comment: @AndréRoggeriCampos Do you think after disabling the JS on my browser will help me get the desired data that I wanted?

Comment: @AdityaMandal, you can try sleep function from `time` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the URL that the page uses to fetch from and handle the json response.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests 
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

res = requests.get('https://www.myntra.com/amp/api/style/5414881?__amp_source_origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.myntra.com').json()
res = json.dumps(res).replace('null', '""')
data = json_normalize(json.loads(res))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(list(df.columns.values))
print(df[['style.brand.name','style.price.discount.label','style.price.mrp','style.price.discounted']])
```

Use `'style.name'` to get 'Nayo White & Black Printed Tunic' for example.

---

Result (minus headers printout):

[image]

---

Overview of the JSON:

[image]

Comment: This does fetch the data of a product but where did you get that url? @QHarr

Comment: From inspecting the network tab to see how the page was on updating

Comment: Okay, got you anyway could you please upvote this question? Its a good question for those who doesn't know about this.

Comment: Don't have an idea like who did it :/

Comment: You could improve it by adding in your code to the question itself rather than a link would be my suggestion.